# Sum of two inputs on bind

Tags: jquery, bind

Im trying to sumarise two inputs fields on bind.

THis is my function :

```
$j('#calclength, #calcwidth').keyup(function() {
    var s1 = $j('#calclength').val();
    var s2 = $j('#calcwidth').val();
    var s3 = (s1) + (s2);
        $j('.s1').text(s3);
});
```

whereas #calclength, #calcwidth are my inputs and .s1 is a span with result.

At the moment whenever ill insert eg 1 & 2 into inputs the result comes out as 12 instead of 3.

Can you guys advice me what I do wrong here please?

Thank you for your help in advance.
Dom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unary + operator that converts strings to numbers

```
$j('#calclength, #calcwidth').keyup(function() {
    var s1 = $j('#calclength').val();
    var s2 = $j('#calcwidth').val();
    var s3 = (+s1) + (+s2);
    $j('.s1').text(s3);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rTu6T/)

Comment: +1. Wow, how have I come this far without knowing that little hack?

Comment: @Utkanos To be honest, I also learned that today too. Thanks to user `Vitaliy Petrychuk`

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the values to integers, e.g. with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var s1 = parseInt($j('#calclength').val(), 10);
var s2 = parseInt($j('#calcwidth').val(), 10);
```

The second argument sets the *base* to `10` which ensures that numbers are always treated as decimal numbers and not octal (leading `0`) or hex (leading `0x`).

---

Instead of `parseInt()` you could also use the implicit conversion to a number by prefixing it with a `+`:

```
var s1 = +$j('#calclength').val();
var s2 = +$j('#calcwidth').val();
```

---

Which solution is better for you depends on what behaviour you want for strings containing a number followed by garbage; see this example on how the behaviour differs:

```
js> +'123x'
NaN
js> parseInt('123x', 10)
123
```

Comment: +1, the parse variants are good for situations like `"500px"` etc Where you don't want to fail fast because you know there is gonna be px.

Comment: +1. I know that it would mean nothing to an 84k guy but as a 500'er I admit that I should provide info about the `+('123x') = NaN` aspect. Thanks for a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

The values are being read as strings, and so concatenated, not summed. Coerce them to integers:

```
var s1 = parseInt($j('#calclength').val());
var s2 = parseInt($j('#calcwidth').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert them to integers, otherwise they are strings and concatenated, not summed.

```
$j('#calclength, #calcwidth').keyup(function() {
    var s1 = $j('#calclength').val();
    var s2 = $j('#calcwidth').val();
    var s3 = (+s1) + (+s2);
        $j('.s1').text(s3);
});
```